# Return values of @All of functions in podio calculation fields

Tags: podio

I have 5 contacts connected to a company, and i am trying to sort out the ones that does not have an email with the code below.

```
var mailArray = @All of Email with nulls

var temp = new Array()
for (var i = 0; i < mailArray.length; i++) {

    if (mailArray[i].value == null) {
        temp.push("null")
    }
    else {
        temp.push("correct")
    }
}
temp.join(" ")
```

Right now i am just pushing the strings to make sure that the flow is correct, it however returns

```
null null null null null
```

when it should return

```
null correct correct null null
```

since the second and third contact has emails. Can anyone help me or give me a hint, as how to use the return value of the @All of function.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to make sure what you are referring to on the emails. Is it an email field in the contacts app, or is it a text field that is called 'email'? If you are using an email field, then the value at your [i] index is actually another object and not just a string yet. Although it doesn't matter if you are just checking for something existing, but personally I'd like to know which contacts do have emails in the output.

If it is just a text field, then you have a problem with the conditional statement. It should be `===` instead of `==`, but I would personally just rewrite it as `!mailArray[i]`.

I'd recommend changing your output to be a markdown table for legability. Here's the code I ended up with:

```
var mailArray = @All of Email text with nulls

var nameArray = @All of Name with nulls

var temp = new Array()

var table = "Email | Contact \n --- | --- "

for (var i = 0; i < mailArray.length; i++) {

    if (!mailArray[i].value){// !== null) {

        temp.push("correct")

        temp.push(mailArray[i])

        table +="\n"+ mailArray[i] + " | " + nameArray[i] 

    }

    else {

        temp.push("null")

        table +="\n"+ mailArray[i] + " | " + nameArray[i] + "\n"

        temp.push(mailArray[i])

    }

}

temp.join(" ")

write = table
```

And this outputs the following table (made 3 contacts, 2 with emails and one without):

[image]